# How to configure properly Tomcat no of threads and jmeter ramp up period

Tags: java, tomcat7, jmeter

I am doing load testing using jmeter.The configuration paramter for jmeter as follows

no of threads =299
ramp up period=1
loop count=1

This is my configuration for threads in tomcat .I am using tomcat 7

```
<Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="2500" minSpareThreads="2400"/>
```

**I have  used  4 GB of ram**

**MYsql max connection :150**

pooling configuration

```
<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">90</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">28690</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">147</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">100</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">147</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>          
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1</prop>
```

This is my tomcat configuration

```
-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=3g
```

When no of threads  is equal to 298 there is no problem.But,when it is increase to 299 i am getting following error
**org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to `http://localhost:8080` refused**

But,when i increased ramp up period to **10** then there is no error.

So,it seems like the problem is related to tomcat threads and ramp up period of jmeter  .

If higher the ramp up period there is no exception .But,when rampup period is lower i get the exception.

In my case i have configured minSpareThreads =2400 then as far my understanding these minimum  no of threads are always available.

**If concurrent requests hit the tomcat in interval of 1 in my case why there is problem in accepting connection to tomcat?**

**As in my case no of threads=299 which is higher than max threads so still why tomcat is not accepting connection?**
        Any help and suggestion please?

Comment: `maxThreads="2500"`? Really? Come on...

Comment: It is larger system with large no of users .

Comment: you need to know the threads processing time also. If threads are not finishing in time, even a smaller load will fail after some time depending when all threads eat up all your cpu/memory.

Comment: A `Thread` needs a CPU to run. Now, obviously, more threads than CPUs can be run with switching. But this is within reason. If you have `2500` requests being processed _at the same time_ you either a) have a long running request - more threads won't help you here, or b) have a extremely high load - you are going to need to more servers. Having `2400` threads minimum _spare_ means that `2400` threads need to be spawned and are waiting - this isn't free...

Comment: Agree with @BoristheSpider threads are not free, they share the system resources, which are limited. You need to find how much processing power you need and how much parallelism is optimal for your requirement.

Comment: Ok i agreee with you.It might be because of some deficiency of resources.But,one confusion what about ramp up period .For ramp up period of 10 there is no problem? Would you please give it as answer i am waiting to accept it.

Comment: for Ramp-up: 1 sec, you are loading the system instantly with 299 users.   for Ramp-up: 10 Sec, you telling Jmeter to create 299 threads in 10 seconds.... which means by the time it reaches 10th second 1 or more users/threads would have already completed the flow and closed the connection.

Comment: How many host connections are configured? 300 perhaps? One or two used by console or monitor (graphite, etc)? Does tomcat call out to DB? How many JDBC connection pools?
What else is tomcat running?

Answer (score 0):

I know its quite late but I had a very smiliar issue:

In general Tomcat uses a so called HTTP-Connector which handles all requests. By default it uses a Blocking IO (BIO) Connector in Tomcat 7. In Tomcat 8 a non-blocking is used by default.

The BIO-Connector will use 1 Thread per Connection. Until the request has completed the thread will not be available for any other processes (->blocking). The Non Blocking on the other hand can handle many connections per thread and usually you only have as many threads as cpu cores. This will prevent you from running out of threads as it will not exhaust your thread pool (which is ridiculous high at the moment).

This beeing said: When you face a lot of requests per second, you use websockets or long polling you should better switch to the NIO-HTTP-Connector. Although it has a slightly slower throughput if you have a moderate amount of requests/s we found that it scales much much better. (in case of websockets or longpolling it is actually the only real solution!).

To change the connector go to your tomcat's server.xml and look for the Connector entries. There should be 2 - HTTP and HTTPs basically.
The xml-entries have a protocol attribute, set to either `HTTP/1.1` or something like `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol`. Change both entries to `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol` to enable the NIO-Connector. Restart Tomcat.